# Sending Request to JSP file based upon AJAX POST

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send a post request to Java servlet, execute a query based upon this value, and send the information to a jsp file. The query in entered from a text box, and when the user hits enter, I need to jump to a new page to display the value of the query.

This is my post request to the servlet:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    // generate the request url from the query.
    // escape the query string to avoid errors caused by special characters 
    "url": "Search",
    "data": {query : query},

    "success": function(data) {
        console.log("normal search successful");

    },
    "error": function(errorData) {
        console.log("lookup ajax error")
        console.log(errorData)
    }
})
```

I get the AJAX post with:

```
String title = request.getParameter("query");
```

//peform action to get results...

then forward request to JSP page with:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("movielist.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

I am getting no errors but the screen doesn't redirect to the new page in my app...

Am I missing something major here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens because you do AJAX call - the request happens in the background of the page, and therefore when ajax receives response from JSP - it stays "in the background" - the success handler is triggered.

What you could do - is to do regular form submit - then navigate from JSP as you mentioned.

Otherwise - if you prefer to keep AJAX, you can do a redirect manually in the success handler with:

```
 "success": function(data) {
       window.location = "<your URL here>";
  ...
```

The URL to redirect to you can pass from JSP that can return json object with it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple :).

Comment: Welcome, could you upvote/accept my answer if you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

AJAX works correctly, if you look @ console it should be print a line. Do your redirect part in your success block.